# AutoFixture constrained string parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nunit, autofixture

Is there a simple way to specify a list of possible values for the parameter orderBy? Not one by one please, otherwise I would not be making the question. I want to specify that orderby makes sense only if it is chosen from a predetermined list. Suppose the list is very large...still not random. This cannot be that hard...no single example of such a simple task.

```
[Test, AutoData]
public override void IndexReturnsView(int? pageIndex, int? pageSize, string orderBy, bool? desc)
{
    .....
}
```

EDIT:

All I want is to read the possible values from a list as I would do with the ValueSource attribute. However, it seems not to work with AutoFixture. If I specified e.g. `[ValueSource("GetOrderByColumnNames")]` my test does not work anymore. I have no idea of what I am doing wrong. Unfortunately AutoFixture lacks useful documentation and the examples are very basic. Is there a working example of this scenario that I can use to guide myself here?

This has to be a very common situation, however I have been looking for days with no luck :(.

Appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `[InlineAutoData]` instead?

Comment: But will I place an InlineAutoData for each possible value of orderby? If I have only 20 possibilities that would be too much!

Comment: Moreover. I want to create the possibilities dynamically, i.e. all the property names of some type. There must be a way!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, the problem is that the `orderBy` value should be randomly selected from a list of predefined values, but that list might be too large to use with `[InlineAutoData]`.

The easiest way to do this that I can think of is to introduce a helper type. [This might actually be a valuable addition to the application code itself](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/19/from-primitive-obsession-to-domain-modelling), as it makes the role of various values more explicit, but if not, you can always add the wrapper type to the test code base.

Something like this is the minimum you'll need:

```
public class OrderCriterion
{
    public OrderCriterion(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Value { get; }
}
```

If we also imagine that this class exposes a list of `ValidValues`, you can implement an AutoFixture Customization using the `ElementsBuilder` class:

```
public class OrderCriterionCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customizations.Add(
            new ElementsBuilder<OrderCriterion>(OrderCriterion.ValidValues));
    }
}
```

Then you create a data source attribute for your test code base:

```
public class TestConventionsAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public TestConventionsAttribute() : base(
        () => new Fixture().Customize(new OrderCriterionCustomization()))
    {
    }
}
```

This enables you to write a test like this, which passes:

```
[Theory, TestConventions]
public void IndexReturnsView(
    int? pageIndex,
    int? pageSize,
    OrderCriterion orderBy,
    bool? desc)
{
    Assert.Contains(orderBy.Value, OrderCriterion.ValidValues.Select(x => x.Value));
}
```

Notice that instead of declaring the `orderBy` parameter as a `string`, you declare it as an `OrderCriterion`, which means that AutoFixture will be detect its presence, and the Customization then kicks in.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/48903199/126014